# Finding a particular solution of $y''+4y'+4y=\frac{e^{-2x}}{1+x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am asked to find the general solution to:

> $$y''+4y'+4y=\dfrac{e^{-2x}}{1+x}~~~,~~~x>0$$

I have managed to find the homogeneous solution, which is:
$Ae^{-2x}$ + $Bxe^{-2x}$

I am now trying to find the particular solution. I guessed a particular solution of the form:

$$\frac{Be^{-2x}}{C+Dx}$$

I was hoping to get confirmation if this was the correct choice... I differentiated this particular solution as required to substitute it back into the given equation (which was a beast), only to, when equate coefficients, have all of the coefficients cancel out.

I appreciate any help,

thank you.

Comment: Use the variation of parameters method to find the particular solution

Comment: To check your result:  Computer algebra gives $y(x) = c_1 e^{-2 x}+c_2 e^{-2 x} x+e^{-2 x} (-x+x \log (x+1)+\log (x+1))$.

Answer (score 3):

We have 
$$\left(\dfrac{y}{e^{-2x}}\right)''=\dfrac{y''+4y'+4y}{e^{-2x}}=\dfrac{1}{1+x}$$
thus
$$\left(\dfrac{y}{e^{-2x}}\right)'=\int \dfrac{1}{1+x}\ dx=\ln(1+x)+C_1$$
and
$$\dfrac{y}{e^{-2x}}=(1+x)\ln(1+x)-x+C_1x+C_2$$

Comment: (+) nice........

Comment: thanks! ${}{}{}{}{}:)$

Answer (score 3):

$y'' + 4y' +4y = \frac{e^{-2x}}{1+x}$

$(D^2 + 4D + 4)y = (D+2)^2y = \frac{e^{-2x}}{1+x}$

So, particular solution,

$PS = \frac{1}{(D+2)^2}\frac{e^{-2x}}{1+x}$

Replace $D$ by $D-2$ and isolate $e^{-2x}$,

$PS = e^{-2x}\frac{1}{D^2}\frac{1}{1+x}$

$PS = e^{-2x}\frac{1}{D}\int{\frac{1}{1+x}dx}$

$PS = e^{-2x}\int{(\ln(x+1) + a)dx }$

$PS = e^{-2x}((x+1)\ln(x+1) -x +ax + b)$

Answer (score 1):

Since you identified the double root $r=-2$ for the  homogeneous equation,  let $y=z\,e^{-2x}$ and the differential equation becomes
$$e^{-2x} z''=\frac{e^{-2x} }{x+1}\implies z''=\frac{1 }{x+1}$$ from which everything becomes simple.